# ACC Revit API Automation

Tags: python-3.x, revit-api, revitpythonshell

We are working on some automations through ACC.
We are accessing some Revit models in which we have several linked models. These models have different 'Site Location" positions to be able to place the same model in different positions.
Through the API, we access these linked models and we take the different "Project Locations" of each of the files. The problem comes when we want to assign the "Shared Site" to each of the instances of the Link, which seems to be something that is not accessible from the API. If we have managed to duplicate the Link and through the API method "RevitLinkInstance.Create(doc, element.Id,ImportPlacement.Shared)" assign a position to a single instance, but not to the rest of instances of the same Link, but this process is manual.

I want to know if it is possible to set the "SiteLocations" to the links directly from Dynamo, without going through the pop-up window to choose the Site.